# Error using Grass v.clean

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2.14

I am trying to clean topology of a TAB file in QGIS 2.14.4 and it returns an error message as below
[image]

The weird thing is, I am able to execute this okay on my machine but not my colleague's. The other intriguing aspect is that the v.clean tool seems to work perfectly okay for SHP files on my colleague's computer. What is going on? We tried to fix the path for grass plugin installations and everything but we continue to receive the error message whenever we are trying to perform topology cleaning on TAB files.

I have also noticed that when my colleague fires up their QGIS 2.14.4 they get two messages which I don't:

1. There is a new QGIS version available 2.16
2. You can add more algorithms to the toolbox. Enable additional providers

Does this have anything to do with the tool not working? I do not get these messages.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your colleague's machine, a possible alternative could be to:

1. Convert the TAB file into a shapefile by right-clicking on the layer, selecting the `Save As...` option and set the relavant options such as format and CRS.
2. Clean this shapefile using *v.clean*.
3. Finally, use the `Save As...` option again on the cleaned shapefile to convert it back to a TAB file.

---

The two messages are unrelated to the issue:

1. It's likely that the option `Check QGIS version at startup` is enabled. You can set this from the menubar:

   ```
   Settings > Options > General > Application > Check QGIS version at startup
   ```
2. You can add more tools from various providers such as Orfeo, R, SAGA etc to the *Processing Toolbox* (note that the *Processing* plugin must be enabled). You can do this from the menubar:

   ```
   Processing > Options... > Providers
   ```